# How to stop loop in swiping fade functionality in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying a functionality of swiping images in fade mode.I tried this,its looping continuously.How to stop looping here.

```
 <script language="javascript">
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
 .appendTo('#slideshow');  

 },  1000);

</script>
```

I have three images here in #slideshow.The last slide is redirecting to first slide.its looping continulouly.I wanted to redirect from last slide to google page.Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script language="javascript">
var timer;
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    timer=setInterval(function() { 
      $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
     .appendTo('#slideshow');  

     },  1000);

    </script>
```

now use for clear interval

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

[Ref](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a data attribute to the slide from which you wish to navigate:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/280/280/technics/1/" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/280/280/technics/2/" />
    </div>
    <div data-exturl="http://www.google.com">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/280/280/technics/3/" />
    </div>
</div>
```

In my example I set an arbitrary data attribute on the third slide: `data-exturl="http://www.google.com"`

Then in the code check for the attribute on each slide and navigate if the attribute is there:

```
var timerID;
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    timerID = setInterval(function () {
        var curSlide = $('#slideshow > div:first');
        var extURL = curSlide.data("exturl");
        if (extURL && extURL.length > 0){
            clearInterval(timerID);
             //redirect to page
             //e.g window.location = extURL; or top.location = extURL;
        } else {
            curSlide
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Q8VJL/2/)**

Comment: thanks for reply your code worked stop looping but i want after stop looping redirect to Google page so Give me any idea

Comment: @AdityaHariKishan, just use window.location = extURL; In the fiddle you would need window.top.location = extURL; because you are in an iframe.

Comment: @AdityaHariKishan, you are welcome! please consider accepting the answer so others that search later will know your question was solved.